# Title Attribute not working for an SVG Rect on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, safari

I have an SVG created with d3 that has title attributes set on all of the rects for tooltip popups.  The code works fine in Firefox, but the tooltips don't show up in Safari--neither Mac or Windows. I know the title attribute is being properly set as I can see it in the Safari Web Inspector.

d3 code snip:

```
.append("rect")
.attr("class", "hmCell")
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    return cellWidth*i;
})
.attr("y", 0 )          
.attr("width", cellWidth-cellPadding )
.attr("height", cellHeight-cellPadding )    
.style("fill", function(d,i){
        return colorScales[i](d);
})
.attr("title", function(d,i) { return coldata[i]['PrintName']+": "+d; });
```

Snippet from the Web inspector showing some of the generated html:

```
<rect class="hmCell" x="0" y="0" width="34" height="11" style="fill: #9fee49; " title="V1: Derek"></rect>
<rect class="hmCell" x="35" y="0" width="34" height="11" style="fill: #ee99bb; " title="V2: Blue"></rect>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

SVG elements do not have a title attribute. To get the effect of an html title attribute you need to add a child title element e.g.

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <rect class="hmCell" x="0" y="0" width="34" height="11" style="fill: #9fee49; ">
            <title>V1: Derek</title>
        </rect>
    </svg>
```

Comment: It worked for an svg element in a different part of the code, and it works for the rect in firefox no problem.

Comment: It sure doesn't work for me having a title attribute rather than a title child element. I wrote the code that implements title tooltip support in Firefox FWIW.

Comment: Well, I went and tried to .append('title') instead of setting it as an attribute of the rect and it did work.  Works in both Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Went back and checked.  The other title attribute that was 'working' was working because it was not on the SVG, but on the containing div (which is actually the way I want it, but I had forgotten that I had done it that way.)

Comment: Funny story: If you use this in Chrome, and you haven't set a page <title> in the <head> then the first one of these will become the page title!

Comment: If you want to do this dynamically, you need to namespace the element when you create it: `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title")`  (As with all SVG elements.)

Comment: I wonder if, when we answer questions like this, we should place <svg> tags around the inner elements - or do whatever we can to make things easier for people new to JavaScript.  I wonder if without the <svg> tags, a new person might spend an extra 5 minutes saying to themselves, "Why doesn't this example work?"

Thoughts?

Comment: @Gerald I suspect stack snippets didn't exist when I wrote this answer. The downside of course is that a new person might paste the whole thing into an existing SVG page. So swings and roundabouts, eh?

Comment: If adding `<title>V1: Derek</title>` is not working, then try `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title")`. we need to create SVG in nm, as per @joeytwiddle comment. This works for me.